# Issue in installing an apk file to emulator in MAC

Tags: android, android-emulator

### Getting error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]

I am installing apk using below steps:

1.Run the emulator,

2.then copy your .apk file and paste into /Users/your_system_username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools,

2.1. if you are not able to find sdk path in your mac system, do the following steps,Open finder->select Go option on top menu -> select Go to Folder option -> it will popup a window with a textfield: /Users/your_system_username/Library/Android/sdk/ -> now open platform-tools folder and paste your copied .apk file.

3.Now open terminal and type the following: cd Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
execute the following in your terminal: ./adb install yourapkfilename.apk

4.if you get the following error message: error: no devices found - waiting for device - follow the step 5.

5.Run your emulator from Android Studio, once emulator active then repeat step 4, you will see the success message on your terminal.

Terminal Log:

```
user:platform-tools user$ ./adb install com.apps_v2.apk 
[100%] /data/local/tmp/com.apps_v2.apk
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.apps_v2.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]
```

Comment: If you have an APK with e.g. ARM only native libraries, you can't install that on x86 emulator.

Comment: @laalto I understand that but its not a native library apk. Could you plz suggest what else would have been causing this error?

Comment: Unzip the apk to see what's in jniLibs.